# PHP Losing variable data

Tags: php, variables

I'm having an issue with PHP losing data in a variable. There is quite a bit of data in the variable, because it basically contains a binary file, but I'm wondering if this is cause for it to completely lose it's information.

Looking at a snippet from my code which is used to deal with email attachments:

```
var_dump($data);  
if (array_key_exists('filename', $params) || array_key_exists('name', $params)) {  
    var_dump($data);  
 ...
}
```

The first var_dump gives the desired output of the file:

```
"string(283155) "
--Apple-Mail-5-930065543 ... etc
```

while the second gives an output of:

```
string(0) ""
...
string(0) ""
```

Any idea why this is happening? Does PHP just drop data in variables if they are really large? (I didn't think so, as I've never had this problem before)

If so, any workaround?

Thanks!

Edit: also worth mentioning that there is no code missing between these statements. I also just tried it with a shorter string and I'm getting the correct output for both var_dump calls

Comment: What happens if you have a short string in $data? Just to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Could you add another var_dump after the if-statement to see what the ouput is then?

Comment: Tried making a short string in the $data variable, and I get output from both var_dumps. Hm..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should never happen. $data gets purified somewhere between var_dumps.  It's hard to say where $data gets changed without seeing the code, but I had similar problems when I worked with old code that overused include.
For example,

```
$data = "my_data";
include "file1.php"  // $data can be changed here !
print($data); // not "my_data"  anymore.
```

Comment: This was close to my issue...the variable was being used outside of the places I had thought it was being used and this was causing issues. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, PHP is definitely not deleting arbitrary variables. Some reasons that could lead to that behaviour:

- You are using the variable `$data` for something else between the two calls to `var_dump()`
- If `$data` is global it might be modified by another function.
- You have another `var_dump()` that you think is the one printing `$data`, but that actually prints another variable
- `$data` is a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) (assigned by `=&`) and the referenced variable is modified.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like one of:

1. You use $data outside its scope. E.g. it is global but you use it in a function() block. In that case you must declare access to this global in your function block: globabl $data.
2. You use references. You will probably want to convert this into ordinary variable semantics, but you'll have to be careful that code which assumes reference semantics is fixed accordingly. (The PHP manual has a section on references, it's worth reading.)

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- `$params` is not an array - the script you thought was supposed to assign it as an array failed - so the `if` expression resolves to false.  Check your error reporting level to make sure it includes `E_ALL  & E_NOTICE` and see if 'not an array' errors show up in your log.  You are also calling `var_dump()` on $data (after you empty out all array values) or on some other variable again later on down your script, making you *think* the second `var_dump()` is being called.
- `$params` *is* an array, but neither of those keys exist within it, so the `if` expression resolves to false.  You are also calling `var_dump()` on `$data` (after you empty out all array values) or on some other variable again later on down your script, making you *think* the second `var_dump()` is being called.
- Your PHP build is not the official build and contains added functionality of `var_dump()` to take the variable by reference, and empty all array values while preserving keys.  Or perhaps it makes `if()` change scope.  This doesn't seem like a value-added feature, so best not use anything but the official build.
- You are not correctly describing the behavior or have excluded code in between the lines which would help explain it.  You are missing semicolons and the list of known keys in $param, so it's safe to assume this isn't the real, full code.

Answer (score 0):

Strange I see the same behaviour. But now only for a specific value

```
// print "Entering getFieldVisibilityPermission(".$fld_module.",". $userid.",". $fieldname.") method ...";
// next line looses $userid only when it has value 12 for value 11 it has no problem
// require('user_privileges/user_privileges_' .$userid. '.php'); -> results in user_privileges_.php 
// require('user_privileges/user_privileges_' .$userid. '12.php'); -> results in user_privileges_1212.php
```